# Can't save custom post type fields

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development

I'm making a plugin to register participations on a contest.
I am using Magic Fields.
On my development server, when I put an entry as a normal user all the data is saved on db and it shows in backend. everytime I try to edti fields as admin, it don't save and send me to "wp-admin/edit.php"

Here's my saving function

```
    add_action('save_post', 'add_fields_contest', 10, 2 );

    function add_fields_contest( $id, $post ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
    if ( $post->post_type == 'contest' ) {
        update_post_meta( $id, 'userid',                $_POST['userid'] );
        update_post_meta( $id, 'title',             $_POST['title'] );
        update_post_meta( $id, 'name',          $_POST['name'] );
        update_post_meta( $id, 'age',           $_POST['age'] );
    }
}
```

All fields exist, I have a metabox created and I really don't know why this isn't saving.

Comment: You don't need to include : require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');, is it because of Magic fields ?

Comment: Yes, it was, sometimes I get in trouble by not adding it

Answer (score 0):

Try debug

```
add_action('save_post', 'add_fields_contest', 10, 2 );

function add_fields_contest( $id, $post ) {
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
if ( $post->post_type == 'contest' ) {
    update_post_meta( $id, 'userid',                $_POST['userid'] );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'title',             $_POST['title'] );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'name',          $_POST['name'] );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'age',           $_POST['age'] );
    echo 'Saving data to post id: '.$id;
    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
}
```

I will recommend "**Advanced Custom Fields**" plugin

Comment: Tried this, it isn't even firing my save_post action :|

Comment: Try remove require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php'); and make sure post_type is 'contest'

Comment: Did it, got the same result. Tried to register a new post_type with another name, same backend fields. I can add a participation and edit it. If I connect it with frontend and add a new participation from front end.. it stops working

Comment: are you use this func in theme/functions.php ?

Comment: I created a plugin, and using it all just in plugin

Comment: Got it! Apparently it as a problem in my front end saving function! :) Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Nice to hear :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but as I understand. Front-end submissions are save and pluggable is need (because of Magic Fields) but maybe causes redirection from the backend, so you can try :

```
function add_fields_contest( $id, $post ) {
   if(!is_admin()){
       require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
   }
   if ( $post->post_type == 'contest' ) {
    update_post_meta( $id, 'userid',                $_POST['userid'] );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'title',             $_POST['title'] );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'name',          $_POST['name'] );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'age',           $_POST['age'] );
  }
}
```